# VB.NET Deleting last item from 2 listboxes at once won't work

Tags: vb.net, listbox

I'm working on a program called "Smart Search". In the "customize search" form,
I made it possible to delete items. Well, the problem here is that it's two listboxes. One for what you should search for and one for what happens when you search: https://i.stack.imgur.com/OPzr5.png

Oh, and btw. When you select an item in one of the listbox, the same selectedindex will be selected in the other.

But when I delete the *last* item(s) in the list I get a error.
I think it's something wrong with my code but I can't find anything wrong with it.
The code: http://pastebin.com/LRBfx5DL

Comment: can you put the code in stack overflow rather than in a link?

Comment: It's too much, sorry

Comment: Just add the code that does the deleting of list of items

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
Private Sub rembtn1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles rembtn1.Click
    Dim index As Integer = ListBox1.SelectedIndex
    If index <> -1 Then
        ListBox1.Items.RemoveAt(index)
        If index < ListBox2.Items.Count Then
            ListBox2.Items.RemoveAt(index)
        End If
        save()
    End If
End Sub
```